# Understanding the algorithm for Newton Fractals

Tags: c++, algorithm, fractals

I am having trouble understanding the equation for newton fractals. My professor gave a a general format to follow, but it is still coming out a bit confusing when I am reading over it. I was wondering if anyone can help clarify or simplify what he is talking about. So the parts I am most confused with is

- Whatis the 'a'?
- What are the conditions for the loop and why would I be resetting counter if it is my condition to leave the loop?
- Is (x, y) the (real, imaginary) part of the complex number?

This is the picture of the algorithm he gave: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJH41.jpg

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the 'a'?

A complex number that generalizes the formula. Choose 1 for a Newton iteration.

---

> What are the conditions for the loop and why would I be resetting counter if it is my condition to leave the loop?

You seem to miss the fact that you are trying to generate an *image*, setting the color of each pixel.

So, you have two nested loops that scan the pixels and, for *each pixel*, a loop that iterates the formula. That's the one that resets the counter and the initial value of z each time.

The condition of that loop are clearly expressed after this statement:

> The iteration should continue while each of the following conditions is true.

Basically they limit the number of iterations and extablish a minimum tolerance. Note that z<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>2</sub> and z<sub>3</sub> are the roots of the third degree polynomial.

---

> Is (x, y) the (real, imaginary) part of the complex number?

Not quite. The values of x and y are the *coordinates* of the pixels in the resulting image and are *used* to generate the real and imaginary part of the intitial value of z.

More details are probably written in the previous page, that you haven't posted.